# flip columns in bootstrap with button click

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to figure out something which I think should be fairly easy.  I have a basic Bootstrap layout shown here:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6" id="tallyForm">
          some content on left side
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
              <button class="btn btn-default" id="flipForm">Flip Form</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6" id="studentImage">
          image loaded here...
        </div>
    </div>
```

I simply want the button to flip the tallyForm and the studentImage divs, left to right, then click again and it goes back to normal.  I have jquery in my project so I'm assuming I attach a click event to the button and do something with the push or pull classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the solution, that reloads all html, you can use bootstrap way to push and pull the columns.

Simply toggle the class that makes the effect. Working example: http://www.bootply.com/JzaVGZORKy

```
$('#flipForm').click(function(e) {
    $('#studentImage').toggleClass('col-md-pull-6')
    $('#tallyForm').toggleClass('col-md-push-6')
})
```

Comment: I marked this the answer because this is closer to what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I just stored the content of one `div`'s `.html()`, then swapped them. Had to move the button out to its own row, otherwise it got moved too.

**JQuery**

```
$('#flipForm').click(function(){
    var temp = $('#tallyForm').html();
    $('#tallyForm').html($('#studentImage').html());
    $('#studentImage').html(temp);
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6" id="tallyForm">some content on left side</div>
    <div class="col-md-6" id="studentImage">image loaded here...</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <button class="btn btn-default" id="flipForm">Flip Form</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

[bootply](http://www.bootply.com/GEHSQc4hYd)

Comment: Slightly more hacky than I'd like, but it does the trick.  When I kept the button in the left div, it lost the functionality after the first click.  So I just took it out like you suggested.  Thanks!